# Work with <ul> and <li> with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<li class="active">Menu1
    <ul id="first" value="">
        <li value="10">Whatever</li>
        <li value="15">Whatever</li>
        <li value="20">Whatever</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Menu2
    <ul id="second" value="">
        <li value="30">Whatever</li>
        <li value="35">Whatever</li>
        <li value="40">Whatever</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Okay that's the HTML, so let me see now if I can describe the behavior I want.

Each `<li>` with a `value` is clickable. When that `li` is clicked, I want it to set the parent `<ul>`, that initially has a blank `value`, to whatever the `value` is of the `<li>` that was clicked. Basically try and mimic the behavior of a `select` box, because that's how the CSS is styling these elements anyway.

Comment: Why don't you use a select box?

Comment: Was easier to style these elements after using Photoshop to create the design this way =/

Comment: Hmm. Depending on what you want to do with that in the end you should really consider using select boxes. E.g. screen readers will not recognize that this should actually be some kind of form element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('li > ul > li').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().attr('value',$(this).attr('value'));
});
```

We set a click event on all internal li elements, then, when clicked, we set attribute "value" of a parent element with "value" of clicked element

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul > li').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().attr('value',$(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`value` is not a valid attribute of `UL` and has been deprecated from `LI`.  With that said, here's how to handle click event for an LI and get the parent UL:

```
$('li').click(function() {
  var clickedLI = $(this);
  var parentUL = $(this).parent();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
in handler:

$(this).parent().attr("value", $(this).attr("value"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('ul > li[value]').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('ul').attr('value', this.value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mDmsW/3/